# Error installing deb file - Reading package list error

Tags: debian, apt, kali-linux

I am trying to install Nessus 8.9.1-debian6 on Kali Linux 2020.1

## Problem

```
[kali@kali:~/Downloads]$ sudo apt install ./Nessus-8.9.1-debian6_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Problem parsing dependency 53 of nessus:amd64=8.9.1
E: Error occurred while processing nessus (NewVersion2)
E: Problem with MergeList /home/kali/Downloads/Nessus-8.9.1-debian6_amd64.deb
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

*Note: the .deb file I am trying to install has a sha2556 sum that matches the value on the manufaturers website*

### Additional details

#### /etc/apt/sources.list

```
[root@kali:~]# grep -v "^#" /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -v "^$"
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

## What I've tried so far

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.bad
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status


sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt-get clean
```

I may just revert the VM but I was hoping for some additional troubleshooting steps to understand the error more (and possibly fix it).

Comment: Is it possible to install it just using `dkpg -i package.deb`?

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Comment: Please add an answer to this post of exactly what you did to solve your issue and accept it when you get a chance. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to give you credit for the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I followed [kemotep's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/276845/kemotep) advice and ran the following:

```
sudo dkpg -i ./Nessus-8.9.1-debian6_amd64.deb
```

This solved the problem.  Thank you very much [kemotep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/276845/kemotep)!